# How to launch an interactive command line interface program from Java?

Tags: java, linux, bash, foreground

I have a Java program that needs to launch an interactive command line interface C program  in the foreground. I need this to work in both Windows and Linux.

In Windows, everything works fine. I am able to launch my program in the foreground with `cmd` as follows:

```
command = "cmd /c start \"My_C_Program\" /MAX /WAIT My_C_Program ";
theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

In Linux, I am unable to do the same with `/bin/bash`. No matter what I try, the process always runs in the background:

```
String[] commands = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "./My_C_Program" };
theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

I know that I can retrieve the output from the background process but this is useless since the program is interactive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even elaborate workarounds :)

Comment: `bash` is a shell not a windowed program, try with `xterm` or something windowed

Comment: @RC. Thanks. That was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this instead:

```
String[] commands = { "gnome-terminal", "-x", "-c", "./My_C_Program" };
theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

Not sure will it work. Didn't try it.

Maybe you don't have gnome-terminal but something else like x-term. It should be almost the same.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue.